# put the appBar at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, material-ui

[image]

I have a project in order to monitor employees and I have an interface for user modification within the site, and at the bottom of this interface there is this blue-surrounded area which is "bottom App Bar", but I could not control its own style and I want it to be fixed at the bottom of the page even with the scroll.

In addition, "bottom app bar" did not appear on the page.

Noting that the first image is the image pulled from the website for which I want to create an interface similar to the image.

And the second image is the page that I made, but it lacks the "bottom App bar"

[image]

How can I solve my problem?

```
const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        root: {
            flexGrow: 1
        },
        paper: {
            padding: theme.spacing(2),
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
        },
        resize: {
            fontSize: 19,
            color: '#828588',
            borderBottom: '1px solid #e4e4e4',
            borderBottomColor: '#384047'
        },
        label: {
            color: '#d5d6d7',
            fontWeight: 560,
            fontSize: '1rem',
            fontFamily: 'Gotham Pro,Proxima Nova,arial,serif',
        },
        textField: {
            color: '#828588',
            background: 'transparent',
            paddingTop: '0.5rem'
        },
        appBar: {
            [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
                width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
                marginLeft: drawerWidth,
            },
        },
        dot: {
            height: '25px',
            width: '25px',
            borderRadius: '50%',
            display: 'inline-block'
        }
    }),
);

const MySettings: FC = () => {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            {/*<Container maxWidth="lg" style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>*/}
            <Grid container xs={12} md={12}>
                <Grid item xs={1} md={1}>
                    <Avatar style={{width: '5.4rem', height: '5.4rem'}} alt="Remy Sharp"
                            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80? 
                ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGVyc29ufGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb- 
                1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"/>

                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={11} md={11} spacing={3}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} spacing={3}>
                        <label className={classes.label}>Full name</label>
                        <TextField
                            className={classes.textField}
                            fullWidth
                            name="name"
                            placeholder="Enter UserName"
                            variant="standard"
                            style={{
                                // paddingTop:'2.3rem',
                                display: 'flex',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                flexGrow: 1,
                                position: 'relative',
                                color: '#828588',

                            }}
                            InputProps={{
                                classes: {
                                    input: classes.resize,
                                },
                            }}
                            defaultValue="Hiba Youssef"
                        />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item style={{marginTop: '2.4rem'}}>
                        <label className={classes.label}>Email</label>
                        <TextField
                            className={classes.textField}
                            fullWidth
                            name="email"
                            placeholder="Enter Email"
                            variant="standard"
                            style={{
                                // paddingTop:'2.3rem',
                                display: 'flex',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                flexGrow: 1,
                                position: 'relative',
                                color: '#828588',

                            }}
                            InputProps={{
                                classes: {
                                    input: classes.resize,
                                },
                            }}
                            defaultValue="hibatallah69@gmail.com"
                        />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item style={{marginTop: '2.4rem'}}>
                        <label className={classes.label}>Password</label>
                        <TextField
                            className={classes.textField}
                            fullWidth
                            name="password"
                            placeholder="Enter New Password"
                            variant="standard"
                            style={{
                                // paddingTop:'2.3rem',
                                display: 'flex',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                flexGrow: 1,
                                position: 'relative',
                                color: '#828588',

                            }}
                            InputProps={{
                                classes: {
                                    input: classes.resize,
                                },
                            }}
                            defaultValue="......"
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item style={{marginTop: '5rem'}}>
                        <Typography style={{color: '#d5d6d7', fontWeight: 640, fontSize: '1.8rem'}}>
                            Your color theme
                        </Typography>
                        <Grid item spacing={8} container  style={{marginTop: '0.6rem'}}>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(123, 104, 
                             238)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 161, 
                            47)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 87, 
                            34)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(244, 44, 
                             44)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 
                            252)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(65, 105, 
                             225)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(95, 129, 
                            255)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(10, 180, 
                            255)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(8, 199, 
                            224)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(7, 160, 
                           146)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(29, 185, 
                           84)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(46, 165, 
                            44)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(117, 115, 
                           128)'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <span className={classes.dot} style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}></span>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>     
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MySettings;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right here

```js
        appBar: {
            [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
                width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
                marginLeft: drawerWidth,
            },
        },
```

you could probably just add

```
                position: "fixed",
                bottom: 0
```

so that way you have this

```js
        appBar: {
            [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
                width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
                marginLeft: drawerWidth,
                position: "fixed",
                bottom: 0
            },
        },
```